# How to remove foundry nuke?

Tags: 14.10

I have ubuntu 14.10, and Foundry Nuke 7.v2, in order to upgrade it I want first of all remove it and then install new version. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Delete all files from the following locations...

Destination directory:
    /usr/local/Nuke9.0v6

Start Menu folder:
    /usr/share/applications/Nuke*

Home folder:
    /home/$USER/.nuke